# Zend framework validating forms

Tags: validation, zend-framework

I am trying to create a form element for the user to input a date but I keep getting this error:

> Invalid validator provided to addValidator; must be string or
>   Zend_Validate_Interface  Dont know what im doing wrong

```
//here is my form code for the date element
    $Commenced_Trading_Date = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Commenced_Trading_Date');
        $Commenced_Trading_Date->setLabel('Commenced Trading Date')
            ->setRequired(true)     
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addvalidator(array(array('Date', true, array('format'=>'j F Y'))));
```

That is the only code I did. Please help

Comment: try this, addValidator('date',true, array('dd-mm-yyyy'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method **addValidator** doesn't take a single array as parameter. The arguments are :

1. Name of validator as string or a validator object (for custom validators) - ***Mandatory***
2. boolean flag, BreakChainOnFailure - *Optional*
3. Options array - *Optional*

See the Zend API description:

```
  addValidator(string | \Zend_Validate_Interface $validator, bool $breakChainOnFailure = false, array $options = array()) : \Zend_Form_Element
```

You can use the Date validator either as :

```
   $Commenced_Trading_Date->addvalidator('Date', true, array('format'=>'j F Y'));
```

Or:

```
   $validator = new Zend_Validate_Date(array('format' => 'j F Y'));
   $Commenced_Trading_Date->addValidator($validator);
```